# ant.properties vs release-signing.properties

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using Cordova 5.4.1.
I'd like to create a signed APK for android.

I followed this:
https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/09/signing-apache-cordova-android-app-release/

^^^^ But this doesn't work, it ignored my ant.properties file.

**ant.properties**

```
key.store=example.keystore
key.alias=example
```

So instead I followed this:
http://shallowsky.com/blog/programming/cordova-create-signed-app.html

And it worked! But I used a file called release-signing.properties (instead of ant.properties)

**release-signing.properties**

```
storeFile=example.keystore
storeType=jks
keyAlias=example
```

Btw, to initiate the build I type in the command:

```
cordova build android --release
```

So I guess release-signing.properties is the way to go for Cordova 5+ ?

(I'm just not sure if I should use ant or not. I guess not because it doesn't work :/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This was the newer way of doing things in 5.4.1. It is still an option with 6.0.+ as well. [Cordova Docs for Signing an App](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/#signing-an-app)

In case you have updated to 6.0.+ cordova, or anyone else who sees this, we've found it easiest to use the `build.json` file option: [Cordova Docs for using build.json](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/#using-buildjson)